# Words that usually would follow the verb "приняться"

Tags: выбор-слова, одним-словом

Is there any way to refine the definition of the word "приняться"?

[The Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EF%F0%E8%ED%FF%F2%FC%F1%FF&all=x) gives the following definition:

> ПРИНЯТЬСЯ, примусь, примешься; принялся, -лась, -лось; принявшийся;
>   св. 1. за что и с инф. **Начать какое-л. дело, приступить к чему-л.** П.
>   за работу, за дело, за уроки. П. за уборку, за стирку. П. за еду, за
>   обед. П. читать, делать уроки, шить. П. кричать, плакать, смеяться.

However, while *приняться* seems to go along well with a wide range of verbs, for example,

> принялся бежать изо всех сил
>
> принялся орать во всё горло
>
> принялся ходить взад-вперёд

it still doesn't fit in well - at least to me (I may be wrong, of course) - in some other cases:

> принялся идти
>
> принялся спать
>
> принялся стоять
>
> принялся означать
>
> принялся принадлежать

So, is it possible to come up with some rule or a principle as to what kind of words would naturally follow the verb *приняться* in Russian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть вот такое объяснение:
М. Панов. Труды по общему языкознанию и русскому языку, Volume 2, О скрытых грамматических значениях, [**стр. 262**](https://books.google.com/books?id=kabSAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA262&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8&pg=PA262#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> ... конструкции с инфинитивом — эллиптичны и представляют собой
>   сокращенные трансформы оборотов: *Он (начал, стал) орать* — с фазовыми
>   глаголами начала действия. При фазовом глаголе возможен только
>   инфинитив несов. вида. Однако весь оборот (с эллиптическим устраненным
>   глаголом типа *Он — орать*) приобретает значение сов. вида: *А что они
>   сделали в ответ? — Они — кричать.* Вопрос: что делали? — не подходит.
>   Такого вопроса требует глагол сов. вида: *начали, принялись, стали,* и
>   вся конструкция имеет состав: *(начать) + кричать.*
>
> С глаголами однонаправленного движения: *ползти, лететь, идти, нестись,
>   плыть, ехать* и пр. не сочетаются фазовые глаголы со значением начала
>   или конца движения. Невозможно: *Он принялся идти, он начал ехать, он*
>   *стал лететь.* Поэтому и невозможны конструкции: *Он — идти. Он — лететь* и
>   т. д. Исключение составляет глагол *бежать*: *Я ему: стой! — а он бежать!*
>   Причина в том, что для этого глагола есть специализированный фазовый
>   начинательный глагол: *пустился (припустился) бежать.* Ср. еще: *Он давай*
>   *бежать,* при невозможности: *Он давай лететь; Он давай плыть.*

Можно добавить еще один фазовый глагол: *взялся.* А вот тезис о невозможности конструкции *принялся идти, начал ехать, ...* здесь очень слаб, нетрудно найти контрпримеры в литературном языке.

Ценное здесь то, что подмечен **принцип:** *принялся, взялся, стал, начал, припустился* — это фазовые глаголы, которые всю конструкцию *Vфаз + Vinf* превращают в составное глагольное сказуемое совершенного вида.

Следовательно, некоторую необычность и странность в звучании с фазовыми глаголами будут давать такие глаголы в инфинитиве, для которых "что-то не так" с заменой на совершенный вид.

*Принялся бежать (сов.)→ побежал, отбежал, сбежал...*

*Принялся идти (сов.)→ пошел

Принялся спать (сов.)→ уснул

Принялся принадлежать (сов.)→ ??*

Можно заметить закономерность, что совершенный вид "странных" глаголов имеет другую корневую морфему, то есть, имеется разрыв в цепи морфологических изменений.

Comment: a very keen observation there, +1

Comment: @briliant, you from Taiwan, did you understand something from this big text? I'm russian, I have master degree in computer science and I don't know half words from this text. Please, do not be offended on my words, but your comment means that you undestand it, and it drives me into a depression, because I don't understand some words from this like: "эллиптичны", "трансформы оборотов", "фазовом глаголе" etc.

Comment: @Alexander , если человек слышит/понимает, что *"принялся спать"* звучит по-русски "как-то странно", то и этот текст, можно быть уверенным, он поймет. И уж тем более, если есть текст всей статьи. А вообще, если бы у Вас стояла задача из прикладной области "синтаксический анализатор русского текста в контекстно-зависимой грамматике", Вы бы и не такие словечки знали :))))

Comment: @Avtokod, просто я читаю и не понимаю половину слов. А человек с Тайваня видимо понял. Мне как-то стыдно за себя стало, вот я и решил убедиться, а точно ли он все понял. Смысл то я понял, но вот некоторые слова... А насчет анализатора - я мобильный разработчик и вряд ли когда-нибудь буду разрабатывать что-то подобное))

Comment: @Alexander , вот, пробежался по своим папочкам, нашёл пример, как сам пишу в документации:  Когда интерпретатор встретит глагол `"+"`, тот содержит описатель, что ему требуются два аргумента. Тогда `"+"` кладет себя как адрес на стек, читается следующее слово `8`, оно тоже безусловно кладется на стек, наконец, слово `"="` делает `SWAP` и исполняет `"+"`. // По большому счету, нет разницы между искусственным языком (математическим или программирования) и естественным. Я утверждаю, что все языки принципиально приводимы к одному и тому же, искусственному, на алфавите {0,1}.

Comment: @Alexander - "**you from Taiwan, did you understand something from this big text? I'm russian**" - The fact that I live in Taiwan doesn't make me less Russian. All such terms like "эллиптичны", "трансформы оборотов", "фазовом глаголе", etc. are not new to me as I met them before in Russian linguistic literature.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of this verb is limited to some specific situations.

Принялся **за дело, за работу** (started working eagerly).

```
Реставратору принесли инструменты, и он *принялся за дело*.
```

Принялся **за (что-то другое)** (started doing some action towards smth. after doing it to another thing).

```
Доев бифштекс, он *принялся за десерт*.
```

Принялся **делать что-либо** - as a rule, in the presence of the teller (started doing something taking his time):

```
Увидев выброшенный кем-то компьютер, он попросил меня подождать и *принялся* его *разбирать*.

Когда мы подошли к реке, он вдруг остановился и *принялся дразнить* уток.
```

Answer (score 0):

Принялся означать, принялся спать и принялся принадлежать - по-русски будет звучать неграмотно. В данном случае выработка общего правила вам лишь повредит. Просто запоминайте наиболее ходовые варианты с этим словом и пользуйтесь ими. А если вам нужно более универсальное слово, используйте не "принялся", а "начал". С ним можно гораздо безопаснее создавать сочетания.